# Why are moving average filters and integrators considered low pass filters?

Tags: lowpass-filter

Why are digital moving average filters and integrators considered low pass filters in baseband signal processing applications?

Comment: Have you tried plotting their frequency responses? What do they tell you? Also, it's not only in that category, it's everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at their frequency responses, as `a concerned citizen` suggests:

```
syms s

integrator = 1/s;
figure(1); fplot(20*log10(abs(integrator)), [0 10000]);

moving_average = [1 1];
[h,f] = freqz(moving_average,1,256,10000);
figure(2); plot(f,20*log10(abs(h)))
```

which gives:

[image: Integrator frequency response]

for the integrator and

[image: Moving average frequency response]

for the two-point moving average.

Answer (score 3):

A filter is called "low pass" if it passes low frequency signal components and, by implication, blocks high frequency signal component.  Just as a coffee filter passes coffee, and blocks coffee grounds.

Moving average filters pass low frequency signal components, and block high frequency ones.  So they are lowpass filters.

I'm not sure that *I'd* unreservedly call an integrator a lowpass filter because of its infinite gain at DC, but it does block high frequency signal components, and passes (or even amplifies) low frequency signal components -- so in that sense it's a lowpass filter.